# Forecasting intermittent demand with PyMC3

Tags: bayesian, forecasting, pymc

I'm trying to implement a model in PyMC3 which relies on a switch with a stochastic condition in the final step, and hence can't pass observed values to the model.

> **Question.** What is the "correct" way to pass observations in a PyMC3 model, when the last step is not a stochastic variable?

Some context: I'm attempting to model intermittent demand using PyMC3 (demand is mostly zero, but occasionally a positive integer). The statistical model I am trying to implement is to model the demand $X_t$ at time $t$ by
$$X_t\sim\begin{cases}
    0 & \text{with probability } 1 - p \\ 
    Poisson(\mu) & \text{with probability } p
\end{cases}$$
(no time dependence), or perhaps more formally,
$$\begin{eqnarray}\alpha & \sim & Bernoulli(p) \\ 
X_t & \sim & \begin{cases} 
    Poisson(\mu) & \text{if } \alpha=1 \\ 
    0 & \text{if } \alpha=0 
    \end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}$$

I attempted to implement this model in PyMC3 by

> `import pymc3 as pm
>  from theano import tensor as tt
>
>  with pm.Model() as model:
>      p = pm.Beta('p', alpha=1, beta=1)
>      mu = pm.Gamma('mu', alpha=0.001, beta=0.001)
>      alpha = pm.Bernoulli('alpha', p) 
>      demand_pos = pm.Poisson('demand', mu)
>      obs = pm.math.switch(tt.eq(alpha, 1), 0, demand_pos)`

The issue is that `obs` is not a distribution, and so has no `observed` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a potential for this, which just gets multiplied to your likelihood. See e.g. https://discourse.pymc.io/t/how-to-set-up-a-custom-likelihood-function-for-two-variables/906/2.